# query inside channel entries tag

Tags: channel-entries, relationships, channel

I have a channel entry and I can return the {author_id} but what I would like to do is return more fields from author

```
{title}
{business_name}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
{exp:member:custom_profile_data member_id="{author_id}"}
    <p>{username}</p>
{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
```

Change the username tag in any member_field you like,

List with the variables to use:
[ee user-guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/member/index.html#id7)

or you can also use your own custom tags